# O365 - Options Field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 2 lists (A and B [3,000 records each]) with columns "Migration Status" each. Now, what I want to do is to get the total of `"Migration Status = Not Started"` for the 2 lists and sum it then display the total to list C.

I tried working on the Workflows, but can't seem to figure out the correct process to it.

Hoping to get answers from you all.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on SharePoint Online you can use MS Flow to achieve this.  Select the appropriate trigger.

1. I have used schedule to trigger the workflow every 5 mins.
2. Use 'Get Items' Action for the List A. Passing the OData filter Migration Status [I have MS Column] eq 'Not Started'
3. Use 'Get Items' Action for the List B. Passing the OData filter Migration Status eq 'Not Started'
4. Create Item in the List C by using following function:

   **add(length(body('Get_items')?['value']),length(body('Get_items_2')?['value']))**

Here are screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter by and Group by features under View creation setting on the list 'C'.

1. Add list C with two lookup columns one from each list (A and B)
2. Create a new view with filter of  Migration Status= Not started for both lookup columns
3. Apply 'Group by' with also apply 'Total'

Comment: Thanks CJS for the response. I have provided limited information. Now List C have the columns "Migration Type", ("Not Started", "In Progress", "Migration Completed") -> These 3 columns will display the totals of the migration status of List A and List B. Not sure if it is possible though, but I just wanted to get everyone's thoughts on this. Is there a way to do this without coding involved?